# how to call a python script inside another python script where both in the same directory?

Tags: python, python-2.7

i have two script--script1.py and script2.py. Now i want to call script1.py with in script2.py.
algo will be like this--

IF condition:
  run script1.py #through command line
ELSE :
  exit

Answer (score 2):

In `script1.py` place this:

```
def main():
    do something

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

In `script2.py`:

```
import script1

if condition:
    script1.main()
```